# ng2-smart-table set total pages

Tags: angular, ng2-smart-table

Looking at the [server-side pagination example](https://akveo.github.io/ng2-smart-table/#/examples/populate-from-server) it seems like ng2-smart-table only displays the 2 previous and 2 next pages, however I'd like to display the total amount of pages I can have given the page size (if the amount of pages is too big then it'd be shortened to be what ng2-smart-table currently does, but including first and last page like so [1, ..., 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, ..., 27]).

From some other questions I've seen posted it seems like ServerDataSource (rather than LocalDataSource) could be the solution I'm looking for, however I can't find examples or documentation on how to implement it property.